# Create an array using endpoints

Tags: php, wordpress

Wanted to apologize, I'm still learning - I just created a new REST API endpoint and I would like to create an array from it.. How would I go about achieving that?

**Id like to create an array with the four values, the endpoint, the service URL, the API KEY and the API Value, Secret Value**.

Below, is currently the code that I have:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'tomjn/v1', '/test/', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'tomjn_rest_test'
    ));
});

function tomjn_rest_test() {
    return "moomins";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this-:

```
register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', '/author/(?P\d+)', array(
'methods' => 'GET',
'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
'args' => array(
    'endpoint' => 'my_endpoint',
    'url' => 'my_url',
    'api_key' => 'my_api_key',
    'api_value' => 'my_api_value'
   )
);
```

Comment: How would I go about printing out the array in my function? Instead of returning "Hello", how can I print the array?

Comment: @Semir - glad the answer helped. To print out array use `print_r(array_name);` or `var_dump(array_name);`. If using error_log try `error_log('array=' . print_r(array_name, true);` or similar.